# What is the most effective way to prevent Express/mssql API for a react website being vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express

I have created a basic full stack application in which it has occurred to me that it is very vulnerable to SQL injections.

The application is using react but the back end itself is consisting of express/mssql npm packages.

Below is a snippet from my server.js file describing how users will sign up. However if users were to input a drop table statement or even worse a drop database it would compromise the whole system.

Server.js

```
app.post("/admin-Add-Users", async (req, response) => {
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.status(400);
      response.send(err);
    } else {
      try {
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        var body = req.body;

        console.log(body);

        if (body) {
          var email = body.email;
          var password = body.password;

          var queryString = `insert into Login (email,password) values ('${email}', '${password}')`;

          console.log(queryString);

          request.query(queryString, function(err, recordset) {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(400);
            // response.send(err);
          });

          response.status(201);
          response.send("User added ");
        } else {
          response.status(400);
          response.send("no content was provided");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        response.status(400);
        response.send(e);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I understand that stored procedures are safe from injection but I am new to these and would not know precisely where to begin .

However within the npm mssql documentation it does actually talk about sql injections and inbuilt prevention for this(https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#sql-injection).

Here is the example given from the documentation

```
const request = new sql.Request()
request.input('myval', sql.VarChar, '-- commented')
request.query('select @myval as myval', (err, result) => {
    console.dir(result)
})
```

However as of this moment my understanding of how to implement this into my code is null.

What would be the best course of action? Is it a better idea to look further into stored procedures or can this be applied to my code successfully stopping ANY threats of SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone wondering this seemed to fix the issue

```
var email = body.email;
          var password = body.password;

          var queryString =
            "insert into Login (email,password) values (@email, @password)";
          request.input("email", sql.VarChar, email);
          request.input("password", sql.VarChar, password);

          request.query(queryString, function(err, recordset) {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(400);
          });
```